# How to stop WinMail (Vista Home Premium) from starting up automatically?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, email, task-manager, windows-live-mail

Task Manager / Processes shows WinMail.exe;

I don't want it to be there automatically, given that it doesn't even work! (says please use Windows Live Mail etc).

So i looked in Startup folder, and msconfig but WinMail does not appear in either of these.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) utility will show you all the ways various programs are being started and allow you to disable them.